# Session problems when APC is turned on

Tags: php, apache, session, apc

We have a problem with PHP session when APC is enabled on our server.

The app works great without APC. However, since we enabled APC, the sessions seems to be getting mixed up when the server experiences heavy load, i.e. users are randomly logging on as another. Everything reverts back to normal once we disabled APC. We can't seem to find anyone with the same problem, except a related problem with these guys (set-cookie was being cached in MS ASP): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163577.aspx#S2

Anyone else has similar experience? Can you recommend any suggestions?

PS: We have all our sessions handled by files in php.ini. We are also running apache2.

Comment: FWIW I've never had a problem with APC/sessions regardless of load

Comment: What session handler are you using? Which version of PHP/APC?

Comment: We are using PHP version 5.2.4

Comment: hard to tell from here! can you give a little bit more information? is all session data assoziated with the wrong session id? can you reproduce the error and do provide a little output or give me a small script that under heavy load (you can benchmark with eveyr thread getting its own session using siege or something similar) produces this error?

Answer (score 2):

We're having a similar issue here.  APC is only a primary suspect at this point because it's been difficult to reproduce.

We're using Zend Framework w/ session management and the theory is that Zend's code is cached in APC and when the system is under severe load the code is using a previously cached SID instead of the current one.

Our safeguard is to save the session ID inside the session data and compare the values when the session is retrieved.  If the IDs are different we destroy the session and exit.

Answer (score 0):

well please verify that apc really mixes up data... 
the only possible i can think of when this could happen is when it gets full and does a stackoverflow.
please check the usage and maby increase the cache size.

Comment: We are fairly sure this is the case, although it is possible that this is a bug that only happens when two users access a function simultaneously. By having APC enabled, we can serve more req/s hence increases the probability for them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem that crops up with APC where custom session handling objects get destroyed before the session data is saved. It could be unrelated to your problem, but an explicit call to `session_write_close` before the regular PHP shutdown fixes that one.

Your problem sounds a bit different though, but I can confirm that issues do exist.

Comment: Thanks, we will look in to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the post, we had success in reducing this problem with three things:

1) We made extra checks to make sure that the IP is matched to the session ID, and logout the user otherwise. We could then use this to track how often the problem occurs.

2) We switched to XCache and immediately saw lower number of confused session IDs. However, under very heavy load the problem rears its ugly head again.

3) We then double the memory for Xcache in the php config (xcache.size and xcache.var_size) and now the problem is gone.

So we suspect either APC or Xcache running out of memory was the problem. We're still waiting to see if this is a permanent solution.